# Condition inequality in perturbed LS

Tags: normed-spaces, least-squares, inverse-problems, condition-number

I have two matrices $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n,d}(\mathbb{R})$ and $B \in \mathcal{M}_{d,d}(\mathbb{R})$ with $B$ being symmetric definite-positive.

I am trying to find a condition on $A$ for which I have : 
$$Tr(B)Tr(AB^{-1}B^{-1}A^T) < 1$$
or, said differently, by writing $B = M^TM$ with $M \in \mathcal{M}_{n,d}(\mathbb{R})$ :
$$\|(M^TM)^{-1}A^T\|\|M\| < 1$$
For the moment, all I have done is write this with coordinates and try to consider condition numbers but I am clearly lost. 
This specific problem arised when I was working on perturbating a least squares problem, that is why I am considering the condition numbers. I have no other information on the matrices but it is ok to specify conditions for which the inequalities above work.

Comment: $d$ is greater or smaller than $n$?

Answer (score 1):

In any case,
$$
\|A\|\le \frac 1{ \|B^{-1}\|\|M\|  }
$$
is enough.